# Commutator of a group is identity..?

Tags: group-theory

If $H$  is a normal subgroup of $G$, $[G:H]=2$. For $x, y \notin H$ then $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$=id?
Is this true in general?

If so how do we prove this?

Comment: You could prove that $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$ is in $H$.  This can be done by observing that $G/H$ is a group of order 2, so it is abelian, and so the cosets $aH$ and $bH$ commute.

Comment: And the hypothesis that $H$ is normal is redundant. A subgroup of index $2$ is always normal.

Comment: @ChocolateAndCheese After saying that $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}\in H$, how do we say that the commutator id equal to the identity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question has already an answer, actually it can be showed that it is true for only **abelain groups**.

Assume $[G:H]=2$ and $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}=e$ for $x,y\notin H$.

So, let $r\notin H$ then $C_G(r)$ must contains every element not in $H$, i.e $G-H\subset C_G(r)$ and it can not be equal as left hand side is not a group.

So, $$\dfrac {|G|}{2}<C_G(r)\implies C_G(r)=G\implies r\in Z(G)$$

But it means that $G-H\subset Z(G)$ with same reasoning we must have $G=Z(G)$

So, $G$ must be abelian group.

Comment: @messel Can you explain me the line $\frac{|G|}{2}<C_{G}(r)$ implies $C_{G}(r)=G$ implies $r\in Z(G)$.

Comment: @Ryan: since ${|G|\over 2}<|C_G(r)|\implies |G:C_G(r)|<2$ and since
$|G:C_G(r)|$ is pozitive integer we must have $|G:C_G(r)|=1$. now we have $C_G(r)=G$ which means that $r$ commutes with every element in $G$ which means that $r\in Z(G)$.

Comment: @Ryan: Actually, it is even true for infinite groups with a little more diffucult proof.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't true in general. Consider $G=S_5$, the symmetric group of $5$ elements and let $H=A_5$, then $[G:H]=2$, but consider $x=(1 2 3 4 5)$, $y=(123)$, then 
$$(1234)(13)(1432)(13)=(13)(24)\neq e.$$

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not true in general.

Consider the symmetric group $S_3 = \lbrace (), (1,2), (2,3), (1,3), (1,2,3), (1,3,2)\rbrace$, of order 6.
The cyclic subgroup (say) $H = \lbrace (), (1,2,3), (1,3,2)\rbrace$ is normal in $S_3$ and $[S_3 : H] = 2$.
If we take $x = (1,2),y = (2,3) \notin H$, then $xy = (1,2)(2,3) = (1,2,3)$ but $yx = (2,3)(1,2) = (1,3,2) \ne (1,2,3)$.
Thus, $xy \ne yx \Rightarrow xyx^{-1}y^{-1} \ne id$.

Ref: [http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Symmetric_group:S3](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Symmetric_group%3aS3)